# DispatcherServlet doesn't appear to be processing the ModelAndView response

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" 
version="3.0">
  <display-name>audiClave</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>rest.root</param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-    class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/REST/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>base</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>      

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>base</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

base-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure as beans -->
<!-- @Controller, @Service, @Configuration, etc. -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.audiClave.controllers" />

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Here is the BaseController:

```
package com.audiClave.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class BaseController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/index.html")
public ModelAndView home() {
    System.out.println("BaseController: Passing through...");
    return new ModelAndView("home");
    // return "WEB-INF/views/home.jsp";
}
}
```

I call the tomcat service with:

```
http://localhost:8080/audiClave/index.html
```

and this is from the console:

```
BaseController: Passing through...
```

appears in the console window but nothing else. Content returned states:

```
description The requested resource () is not available.
```

Contents of /WEB-INF/views/home.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Audiclave</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello world from audiClave!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem isn't in the file though because if I return

```
return new ModelAndView("xxxx");
```

It is the same result.

It does seem to be library related as it was working before I started changing the libraries (relating to JSTL and JSP) in my project. I don't know the sequence of the libraries I have changed. I must have ended up with something incompatible with tomcat 7.

There is nothing in the tomcat log that indicates a problem. This is the startup log:

```
01/06/2011 9:25:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;.;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Python26\Scripts;C:\Python26\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin;%APPDATA%\Python\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Translate Toolkit;C:\Program Files\Gallio\bin
01/06/2011 9:25:20 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:audiClave' did not find a matching property.
01/06/2011 9:25:20 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
01/06/2011 9:25:20 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
01/06/2011 9:25:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 336 ms
01/06/2011 9:25:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
01/06/2011 9:25:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
01/06/2011 9:25:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'rest'
01/06/2011 9:25:22 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'rest': initialization started
01/06/2011 9:25:22 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'rest-servlet': startup date [Wed Jun     01 09:25:22 EST 2011]; root of context hierarchy
01/06/2011 9:25:22 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/rest-servlet.xml]
01/06/2011 9:25:22 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@62610b: defining beans [baseController,restController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,beanNameResolver,RemedyXml]; root of factory hierarchy
01/06/2011 9:25:22 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/index.html] onto handler 'baseController'
01/06/2011 9:25:22 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/REST/remedies/{language}] onto handler 'restController'
01/06/2011 9:25:22 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/REST/remedies/{language}.*] onto handler 'restController'
01/06/2011 9:25:22 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/REST/remedies/{language}/] onto handler 'restController'
01/06/2011 9:25:22 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'rest': initialization completed in 359 ms
01/06/2011 9:25:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'base'
01/06/2011 9:25:22 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'base': initialization started
01/06/2011 9:25:22 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'base-servlet': startup date [Wed Jun 01 09:25:22 EST 2011]; root of context hierarchy
01/06/2011 9:25:22 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/base-servlet.xml]
01/06/2011 9:25:22 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@848ecc: defining beans [baseController,restController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0]; root of factory hierarchy
01/06/2011 9:25:23 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/index.html] onto handler 'baseController'
01/06/2011 9:25:23 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/REST/remedies/{language}] onto handler 'restController'
01/06/2011 9:25:23 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/REST/remedies/{language}.*] onto handler 'restController'
01/06/2011 9:25:23 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/REST/remedies/{language}/] onto handler 'restController'
01/06/2011 9:25:23 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'base': initialization completed in 297 ms
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
01/06/2011 9:25:23 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
01/06/2011 9:25:23 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
01/06/2011 9:25:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2490 ms
```

As per Biju's recommendation here is the log from after baseController returns the modelAndView:

```
2011-06-01 11:32:59,218 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-11] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'home'
2011-06-01 11:32:59,218 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-11] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'home'; URL [/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'base'
2011-06-01 11:32:59,218 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-11] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'home'
2011-06-01 11:32:59,218 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-11] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

Comment: do you have anything defined in your spring config file (prefix or suffix) which could be altering this path?

Comment: What does Spring's logging show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that home.jsp does not exist in the

```
.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\audiClave\WEB-INF\views
```

directory even though in eclipse it is showing. Wasn't able to see that until I got the logging working properly.
Stopping the server, cleaning, and then republishing seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Register a [ViewResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ViewResolver.html) in the Spring configuration along these lines:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Now you should be able to return "home" from your controller's requestmapped method and it should correctly get resolved to "/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp" page.

Comment: Can you please run it in DEBUG mode and see if something more gets printed in the console.

Comment: Sorry I am new to all this, I have Debug As -> Debug on server. Nothing more appears, is there anything more that I can do to get more detail?

Comment: No worries Hemans - add this to a file named log4j.properties

log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

Add the log4j.properties file to WEB-INF/classes folder. Restart and see if anything more gets printed to the console

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing a dependent library (which is why it fails regardless of what JSP file you specify) and your Spring context is erroring out when it tries to create something. Look carefully in **catalina.out** for a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` and see if you can figure out which class it is missing.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right, but I can't find anything (see my updates)